# What Neovim GUIs have GUI scrollbars as described in vim under :h gui-scrollbars?

Tags: neovim, gvim, scrolling

### TL;DR

I am looking for a Neovim GUI with GUI scrollbars as described in vim under [`:h gui-scrollbars`](https://vimhelp.org/gui.txt.html#gui-scrollbars) (accessed on 2021-08-21).

### What GUI Vim scrollbars are like

```
2. Scrollbars                       *gui-scrollbars*

There are vertical scrollbars and a horizontal scrollbar.  You may
configure which ones appear with the 'guioptions' option.

The interface looks like this (with ":set guioptions=mlrb"):

                       +------------------------------+
                       | File  Edit              Help | <- Menu bar (m)
                       +-+--------------------------+-+
                       |^|                          |^|
                       |#| Text area.               |#|
                       | |                          | |
                       |v|__________________________|v|
 Normal status line -> |-+ File.c              5,2  +-|
 between Vim windows   |^|""""""""""""""""""""""""""|^|
                       | |                          | |
                       | | Another file buffer.     | |
                       | |                          | |
                       |#|                          |#|
 Left scrollbar (l) -> |#|                          |#| <- Right
                       |#|                          |#|    scrollbar (r)
                       | |                          | |
                       |v|                          |v|
                       +-+--------------------------+-+
                       | |< ####                   >| | <- Bottom
                       +-+--------------------------+-+    scrollbar (b)

Any of the scrollbar or menu components may be turned off by not putting the
appropriate letter in the 'guioptions' string.  The bottom scrollbar is
only useful when 'nowrap' is set.
```

For reference here is a **[MacVim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim)** screenshot which shows four scrollbars for the given windows as expected by the setting `guioptions=mlr`:

[image: MacVim with multiple scrollbars]

However, MacVim is a GUI for Vim, not Neovim.

### NeoVim GUIs

There exist already Neovim GUIs with scrollbars which, however, do not implement them in the way as described in the vim help. I have looked at following ones:

1. **[neovim-qt](https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt)** shows only a single scrollbar for the active vim-window on the right which I find insufficient and non-intuitive:
   [image: neovim-qt screenshot]
2. **[goneovim](https://github.com/akiyosi/goneovim)** shows also only a single scrollbar  for the active vim-window on the right as neovim-qt.

Other Neovim GUIs without GUI scrollbars at all (please update if inaccurate)

- [VimR](https://github.com/qvacua/vimr)
- [FVim](https://github.com/yatli/fvim)

### Question

Is there a Neovim GUI which provides GUI scrollbars as described in Vim help?

The best solution I have found is https://github.com/dstein64/nvim-scrollview but since there are many Neovim GUIs I might have overlooked one.

---

#### Sidemark: Personal reasons to have scrollbars in vim

- Familiar visual feedback about document length and current position
  (and yes vim status bar gives also feedback about this: but the string `214,25 16%` needs more mental cycles to process than a scrollbar and provides accuracy I do not always need.)
- Continuously paging a file with varying speed without thinking about number of lines to scroll forwards or backwards
- UI consistency (scrollbar is visible if document does not fit within the window and vice versa)

Note that I am not interested in answers trying to reason that scrollbars are not useful or unnecessary in vim or explaining the different motions available in vim to efficiently navigate by keyboard. I am familiar with them and I know that vim is keyboard-centric. But I consider additional visual feedback useful and I do  occasionally resize a split by mouse and might proceed using the scroll wheel for a while when coming back from another GUI window without vim mode.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Thanks for your comment. I have tried to improve the question. What do yo think?

Comment: I've made an edit, mostly with headers to break things up a bit. I think your "solution" makes one answer, and other answers could point to other GUIs. This would also give you room to flesh out how specifically that GUI has scrollbars, benefits/drawbacks of that one, &c.

Comment: Yes, that looks good with the paragraph headings. I try to keep this in mind for future questions. Thanks a lot. Even though I think I will not get more answers by improving the question further: there simply might not be a Neovim GUI with this particular feature.